# TFS 2013 Release Management Client not communicating with Server

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I am **trying to configure Release Management Client** to work with a Release Management Server for Microsoft TFS 2013 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

I installed (without any errors) the following two from our subscription downloads:

- en_release_management_server_for_team_foundation_server_2013_with_update_4_x64_web_installer_5920525
- en_release_management_client_for_visual_studio_2013_with_update_4_x86_x64_web_installer_5920526

I have **not** installed any Microsoft Deployment Agents.

I have installed and configured the RM server for a SQLExpress db (different from the TFS db in our case) and for now I used my own network credentials (being a member of Administrators group on the server and a member of Default Collection Administrators on TFS, with "Make requests on behalf of others" set to "Allow" on TFS).

When I copy the RM Server URL from "Configure Release Management Server" screen (http://xxx:1000/ReleaseManagement) and paste it into a browser, the page loads without any errors.

However, when the same URL is used in RM Client Configuration, I get an error: "The server specified could not be reached":

[image: The Server Specified could not be reached]

We have VS2012 on the server and VS2013 Ultimate on my own dev machine. 
I tried installing and configuring the client on both the server (Win Server 2008 R2 Standard) and my dev machine (Win 8.1 Pro), and I still get the same error (so I assume the version of VS is not an issue).

Looking at the event log, I get two errors.

ERROR ONE:

**The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found**.: \r\n\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.PlatformHttpClient.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClientResponseRetriever.EndGetAsyncMemoryStreamFromResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult, IPlatformHttpClient platformHttpClient)

.... [edited out for brevity]

Process Name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Release Management\Client\bin\ReleaseManagementConsole.exe

ERROR TWO:

**Error communicating to the web server URL**: http://xxx:1000/ReleaseManagement/account/releaseManagementService/_apis/releaseManagement/

Indeed, when I enter that URL in a browser, I get "**404 - File or directory not found**". Here is what the site structure is:

[image: RM_Site_Structure]

**What I should do to be able to configure our Release Management Client without errors, please?**

Additional observations:

1. I cannot see "Release Management" role on our server, but have seen in mentioned in relation to RM installs.
2. The client installer reads "Release Management Client for Visual Studio 2013 Update 4", whereas instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn593704(v=vs.120).aspx) indicate it should be "Release Management Client for Team Foundation Server 2013 Update 4". Surprisingly, when I ran the installer recommended by that article, the title again read "...for Visual Studio" as opposed to "...for Team Foundation Server".

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're entering the wrong URL. The URL should be `http://<RM Server Name>:<Port>`. No `/ReleaseManagement/`.

The `/ReleaseManagement`/ folder is not for the desktop client, but rather for the approval dashboard.

Comment: Daniel, you are a life saver! Thank you so much... :)

Comment: @Daniel Mann thanks for your point, its resolved my problem and save time.